# Update table 1 when the column value of the table 2 changes ** Without Trigger **

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a column in table 1 when the value of the column in table 2 changes. I'm trying to avoid using a SQL Server trigger as I faced so many issues with the application when the trigger is enabled. Plus it has to be a instant update on table 2. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

**LOGIC**

Get the status of the Maximum due date of the affected prodid and change the buyer in the table 2 for depend on the status

EDIT. I have added the trigger I used. but it is very in-efficient and caused issues

```
    CREATE TRIGGER trg_Update
    ON [dbo].[tblTable1]
    AFTER UPDATE
AS

DECLARE
    @v_orderId int,
    @v_proId int,
    @v_statusId int

BEGIN
    SELECT @v_orderId = OrderID
    FROM inserted

    SELECT @v_proId = ProdID
    FROM tblTable1
    WHERE OrderID = @v_orderId

    SELECT @v_statusId = v.VisitStatusID
    FROM tblTable1 v
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT MAX(DueDate) AS MaxDueDate, ProdID
        FROM tblTable1
        GROUP BY ProdID
    ) t2 ON v.ProdID = t2.ProdID
    AND v.DueDate = t2.MaxDueDate
    WHERE v.ProdID = @v_proId

    IF @v_statusId IN (5, 25)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE tblTable2 SET Buyer= 'CP1' WHERE ProdID = @v_proId
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE tblTable2 SET Buyer= 'CP2' WHERE ProdID = @v_proId
        END
END
```

Comment: This is what triggers do.

Comment: Use a trigger anyway. You will have more problems without them...

Comment: Or perhaps create a view?

Comment: It may be that a view or indexed view is the right approach here. We'd need more *specifics* about the nature of these updates (e.g. if it's a count of matching rows in table 1, or for some reason just a copy of a value, etc).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I added the trigger I used.

Comment: It's not just inefficient, it's wrong. `inserted` can contain *multiple* rows. You assign one row's value to `@v_orderId` (in a non-deterministic fashion) and ignore the remaining rows. Can you better spell out the logic in *words* because at the moment, it looks like you always set `FinishDate = GETDATE()` so most of the remaining code seems pointless.

Comment: It seems that the IF Section has no use since both If and Else Statements are same. and Yes, the correct way of updating Table2 is to use trigger. Also, I believe that it is better approach to use exists or in rather then inner join and you may need to limit number of returned results to 1.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I added the logic. Thanks

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If I'm not using inserted, how do I get the id of the affected row?

Comment: @Simonare Is there an example on using exists or in rather than inner join? thank you

Comment: You do need to use `inserted` - but you need to treat it as a *table* containing multiple rows. There isn't "the" affected row, there are affected row**s**. Ideally you write a single `update` with the `FROM` clause referencing both your real tables and `inserted`.